Passing function to ngtemplate and update component value
I have a checkbox and two buttons to increment or decrement minutes variable from the component. I will have three similar sections which contain same fields. Hence decided to go with ngtemplate way avoiding duplicate code.
Click events make it to the component fine. Issues are:

checkbox value is not updated automatically.
When buttons are clicked, I get an error:
ERROR TypeError: this is undefined (app.component.ts:27)

app.component.html
Testing NGContainer:

<ng-container
  [ngTemplateOutlet]="allowanceTemplate"
  [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{
    allowLabel: 'Lunch',
    cbAction: cbClicked,
    addAction: addLunchMinutes,
    minusAction: minusLunchMinutes,
    cbName: cbChecked,
    minutesOut: lunchMinutes
  }">
</ng-container>

<ng-template
  #allowanceTemplate
  let-allowLabel="allowLabel"
  let-addAction="addAction"
  let-minusAction="minusAction"
  let-cbName="cbName"
  let-cbAction="cbClicked"
  let-minutesOut="minutesOut"
>
  <div>
    <label class="cb-container">
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        checked="cbName"
        name="cbName"
        (click)="cbClicked($event)"
      />
      <span class="cb-checkmark"></span>
    </label>
    <label for="">Minutes:</label>
    <button value="Minus" (click)="minusAction(allowLabel)">Minus</button>
    <label for="" class="innings-values">{{ minutesOut }}</label>
    <button value="Add" (click)="addAction(allowLabel)">Add</button>
  </div>
</ng-template>

app.component.ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, FormsModule],
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrl: './app.component.scss',
})
export class AppComponent {
  lunchMinutes: number = 30;
  cbChecked: boolean = true;

  cbClicked(event: any) {
    console.log('cbClicked ' + this.cbChecked);
  }

  addLunchMinutes(allow: any) {
    console.log('addLunchMinutes ' + allow);
    this.lunchMinutes--;
  }

  minusLunchMinutes(allow: any) {
    console.log('minusLunchMinutes ' + allow);
    this.lunchMinutes++;
  }
}

index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>My app</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <base href="/" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <main-root>Loading...</main-root>
  </body>
</html>

I further tried building the context in the component and passing it to the ngtemplate tag. I get same error:
  lunchCtx = {allowLabel:'Lunch',
    cbAction: this.cbClicked,
    addAction:this.addLunchMinutes,
    minusAction:this.minusLunchMinutes,
    cbName:this.lunchMinsChecked,
    minutesOut:this.lunchMinutes};

<ng-container 
    *ngTemplateOutlet="allowanceTemplate;lunchCtx">
</ng-container>

Stackbliz is available here

change to.
<ng-container
  [ngTemplateOutlet]="allowanceTemplate"
  [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{
    allowLabel: 'Lunch',
    cbAction: cbClicked,
    addAction: addLunchMinutes.bind(this),
    minusAction: minusLunchMinutes.bind(this)
    cbName: cbChecked,
    minutesOut: lunchMinutes
  }">
</ng-container>

the instance of lunchMintues are not passed correctly. now as i am binding the this instance to the function it is working.
Let me know if this helps you

Function calls work well with bind(this). Thank you.
